# In PHP, what is a Tick?

Tags: php

I know that Ticks are not PHP specific and are somewhat related to timing and/or number of operations, but I lack all the understanding that would otherwise allow me to work with them.

Can someone please explain to me what ticks are / do in a simple fashion?

Comment: @Zed +1 for your so good example of a non-PHP specific tick.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a decent explanation [here](http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn62.html).  I have used them in writing daemons.

I think declare() might be planned for deprecation.  I know it was at one point.

**EDIT:** It was the ticks directive that was planned for deprecation.

Comment: `declare()` was never planned for deprecation, but it seems that the `ticks` directive was.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.  The ticks=1 was required for writing daemons with pcntl functions.  I just remember a comment in my code stating that something was getting deprecated.

Answer (score 15):

In PHP, a tick is like an event which is triggered after every n-th statement (the *n* is declared using [`declare`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php)), with a few exceptions such as control structures (`if`, `for`, ...). It is possible to [register a tick handler](http://php.net/register_tick_function), which would be called every tick. This is a very rarely used feature, but sometimes it may be helpful, for example, for simple profiling.

Comment: So what kind of statements are considered tick-trigger statements?

Comment: Well, if control structures don't count as statements, then, as far as I know, every statement can trigger a tick.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20091215033353/http://www.youngcoders.com/php-articles/22319-ticks-php-construct-youve-never-used.html) (found via Google) says that Ticks are

> a underused and powerful feature of PHP that allows you to implement exceptions in PHP4

But you're probably not talking about PHP4, in which case, go with the other answers.

Comment: Also from hte php manual http://th2.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php

It appears to be a low level api for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Ticks have been deprecated as of PHP 5.3, and will be removed entirely at some point in the future. ... Put simply, a tick is a special event that occurs internally in PHP each time it has executed a certain number of statements. These statements are internal to PHP and loosely correspond to the statements in your script.

Comment: I think you will find that PHP ticks have been undeprecated. Looks like you got that from http://www.hackingwithphp.com/4/21/0/the-declare-function-and-ticks, but at the bottom of the post the author has made a note that he admits he was wrong.